# Getting error "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority" - for Intermediate certificate

Tags: c#, certificate

i'm validating a signed DLL with X509Chain class -> Build method.

the problem is that i have the root CA installed, but i don't have an intermediate certificate installed - and i don't want to install it for every machine.

is it possible to verify the signature but ignore intermediate certificates? (Root CA cannot be ignored).

Thanks!